# Change the From field in an email with the mail command under linux without the -a option

Tags: linux, email, config, email-headers, email-confirmation

**Problem:** when I use the `mail` command under linux (Ubuntu Server 16.04) as root to send an email (several scripts on my server do so), the `From:` field in the mail header looks like `From: root@mydomain.org`. I want it to look like `From: admin@mydomain.org`.

**Attempt:** I already found the option `-a "From: admin@mydomain.org"` to add the field to the mail header.

My whole command looks like this:

```
echo "content" | mail -s "subject" "recipient@wherever.org" -a "From: admin@mydmain.org"
```

**Second Problem:** However, I do not want to write the `-a` option at every point I use the `mail` command in a script because this is some kind of hard coding.

**Second Attempt:** My best attempt yet is to write a wrapper, though I think there should be a cleaner method to always add that header field to mails sent with the `mail` command.

**Question:** Does anyone know a better way which does not include hard coding? Still I want to use such a simple command line as above to not make things unnecessary complicated.

Best

Fabian

Answer (score 0):

the `mail` command reads ~/.mailrc or a different startup file given by the environment variable `MAILRC`. (see manpage, http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/bsd-mailx.1.html#contenttoc4)

this file can contain the line `set from=you@example.org`.

```
conf="$(mktemp)"
trap 'rm -f "$conf"' EXIT
echo set from=you@example.org > "$conf"
export MAILRC="$conf"

# now mail will use you@example.org as From:
```